# Is there any way to identify a person's title through NLTK?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nltk

I'd like to be able to extract the title or job position of a person from a short description. 
For example:

- Assistant professor in University of California.
- Owner of car shop in San Francisco,CA.

I'd like to be able to identify the keyword "professor", or ideally "assistant professor", from the first short phrase. In the second phrase, I'd like to be able to identify "owner".

Comment: How do your text look like? Can you upload a larger sample?

Comment: I suggest you to check [Friend of a friend (FOAF)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FOAF) specification and associated tools. Some of the tools probably already handles the free-form to FOAF translation including a heuristics needed for parsing free-form sentences in english